# ASP.NET AJAX and JQuery issue

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an ASP.NET page using the AJAX control toolkit for some controls. A recent update is looking for some more dynamic "flair", and it was recommended I look into jQuery to add some of the functionality. My issue lies here: When I add the jQuery  reference (see below), I get a javascript error when the page loads: "this._form is null or not an object". This seemingly disables all the controls on the page (on load, the page displays some user information and 5 or 6 buttons as a "menu"). All the click handlers seem to get disabled due to this error. If I remove the reference to jQuery, everything works fine. I have also tried writing some jQuery code to create a message when a controls hover event is fired. Even with the js error, that code works, but it still disables the buttons.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" />
```

Any help, ideas, etc would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may sound strange but you need to have an end tag for script tags. So you use :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" ></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" />
```

Comment: I don't know about other versions, but this is definitely the case in IE6.

Comment: @Mario: I actually spent quite a long time figuring this out a couple of years ago. When I saw your script tag ... I even answered the question before reading the whole thing.